# How to split an AngularJS code in separate files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller, angularjs-1.6

Everything is working but when I try to separate my script to external js files, AngularJS is not running.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    $scope.UnitReport = function(){
        alert("aa");
    }
})
//this is just a part of script
;
</script>
```

I separated like:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.UnitReport = function(){
        alert("aa");
    }
})
```

but didn't work.

Also, I separated like:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.UnitReport = function(){
        alert("aa");
    }
})
```

but didn't work again.

How is possible to separate this AngularJS?

P.S.: There aren't any mistakes on the external file link and functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line **creates** the module `MyApp`, because of the `[...]` part:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);
```

As you want to create a controller for this module, you will need to **refer** to it. In your app, you do it directly after the module declaration:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [...]).controller(...);
```

So you create the **module and the controller** in one line.

---

Now what you need is to separate it, so, firstly create your module:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);
```

In another file, create a controller on this module, with the following synthax:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller(...); /* There are no [] anymore -> not a mod creation */
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to separate files on different js.

With the following code you instantiate the module

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
```

In order to grab the existing module and add a new controller to it you should use only one argument, which is the name of the module.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(/*.. Controller code ..*/)
```